# Formal arguments versus 'polemic' arguments in the political arena and news media

Tags: argumentation

Many of us in the technical field are somewhat familiar with formal logic, and computer languages as well as methods of proof of such as induction and deduction, and possiblythe basic concepts of philosophy.

In current political discussion, specifically in the news media and in statements by politicans, for example in televised debates,  it seems to me that another type of argument is being used, which seems to fit the description of 'polemic' arguments.

Where can I find material that discusses the differences between the formal academic argumentative writing and the more common arguments put forward in the news that contain suggestion, innuedo and appeal to emotions? How can a technical person or an acedemic deal with this sort of argument and present our own views successfully?

Comment: See [Rhetoric](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-rhetoric/) : the art of persuasion.

Comment: That helps immensely. Reading through it.

Comment: You can see also [Chaïm Perelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha%C3%AFm_Perelman)'s [new rhetorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_rhetorics).

Comment: See also [Argumentation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentation_theory).